# coisotropic action on $TS^{2n+1}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moment-map

Let $S^{2n+1}$ be the $m$-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Endow $S^{2n+1}$ with the standard metric. Let $S^1$ act by multiplication on $S^{2n+1}$. Then $S^1$ and the canonical action of $SU(n+1)$ are by isometries. Since the actions of $S^1$ and $S^{2n+1}$ commute, $G = SU(n+1) \times S^1$ acts by isometries on $S^{2n+1}$. Lifting the action to $TS^{2n+1}$ we get, that this action is hamiltonian.

In their paper "New examples of manifolds with completely integrable geodesic flows", Paternain and Spatzier say, that $G$ acts on $TS^{2n+1}$ multiplicity-free/coisotropic.

That means:

1)
Their exists an $\operatorname{Ad}^*_G$-equivariant momentum map 
$$\Phi \colon TS^{2n+1} \to \mathfrak{g}^*$$
2)
For $\alpha \in \mathfrak{g}^*$ the isotropygroup $G_\alpha$ acts transitively on the connected components of $\Phi^{-1}(\alpha)$.

I'm not sure how to show now, that this action is really multiplicity-free/coisotropic, because I don't know how to calculate the momentum map and the preimage effectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Since $S^{2n+1}$ is a Riemannian manifold one can identify $TS^{2n+1}$ with the cotangent bundle $T^*S^{2n+1}$. The latter is well-known to carry a canonical symplectic structure and a momentum map.

2) This condition can be rephrased as $\Phi/G:T^*S^{2n+1}/G\to\mathfrak{g}^*/G$ being finite to one. Let $G_0\cong SU(n)\times S^1$ be the isotropy group of a point $x\in S^{2n+1}$. Then $T^*S^{2n+1}/G=T^*_xS^{2n+1}/G_0=V/G_0$ where $V=\mathbb{C}^n\oplus \mathbb{R}$.  Hence $V/G^0=\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\times \mathbb{R}$. Now the first factor is mapped to the quotient of $SU(n+1)$ while the second to $(Lie S^1)^*$. This shows that $\Phi/G$ is finite to one.

Remark: More generally, the cotangent bundle $T^*X$ of a homogeneous space $X=G/H$ is the fiber product $G\times^H\mathfrak{h}^\perp$ where $\mathfrak{h}^\perp\subseteq\mathfrak{g}^*$ is the annihilator and the moment map is $[g,\xi]\mapsto Ad^*(g)\xi$. So multiplicity-freeness means that $\mathfrak{h}^\perp/H\to\mathfrak{g}^*/G$ is finite to one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. What do you mean by $\Phi/G$ is a finite to one map. Furthermore I'm not quite sure, what you mean by "the first factor is mapped to the quotient of $SU(n+1)$".

Comment: So we have also, that if $G$ acts multiplicity-free on $T^*X$ then it acts multiplicity-free on $TX$?

Comment: With "finite to one" I mean a map with finite fibers.

Comment: If $L: TX \to T^*X$ is the identification given by the riemannian metric, I don't see why the canonical lifted action of $G$ on $T^*X$ should be the same as the induced action given by the identification of the lifted action of $G$ on $TX$. SInce a priori this actions are different, multiplicity-freeness of one of these shouldn't imply multiplicity-freeness of the other one. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: First, the actions are the same since $G$ preserves the Riemannian metric. Second, there is no genuine momentum map on $TX$ since a tangent bundle does not have a natural symplectic structure. It is only via $L$ that there is a momentum map on $TX$.

Comment: Damn, you are right. Somehow I mixed up the meaning of "canonical lifted action" and thought about the induced action on $TX$ given by the $G$ acting by derivatives. Would it be possible for you, to clarify a little bit more, what you mean by: "the first factor is mapped to the quotient of $SU(n+1)$"?